# Insert Non-Duplicate records to copy table with updated date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently working on a project where I have 2 SQL Server databases and need to copy new records into archive database and append with updated date.  Example:

**Existing DB:** `dbo.A.Category(Id, Name)`

Copy new records (no duplicates) to:

**Archive DB:** `dbo.B.Category(Id, Name, ArchiveDate)`

How do I copy only changed records from the existing database to the archive database?  This is in SQL Server.

Comment: How do you tell what rows have been "changed"? Do that have a "last updated" date?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the EXCEPT operator for this.  For example:

```
INSERT INTO archiveCategory (id,name,creationdate)
SELECT id,name,current_timestamp
FROM    (
    SELECT id,name
    FROM myDB.dbo.category
    
    EXCEPT

    SELECT id,name
    FROM archiveDB.dbo.category
    WHERE creationdate = (SELECT max(creationdate) from archiveDB.dbo.category a2 where a.id = a2.id )
    ) delta
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a `MERGE` statement.

I have made the following assumptions about what you're trying to achieve:

- the `[Id]` column in `dbo.A.Category` contains unique values
- the `[Id]` column in `dbo.B.Category` is not an identity column and values correspond to matching `[Id]` values in `dbo.B.Category`
- you only care if updated `[name]` values in `dbo.A.Category` have been changed, not if they've been updated with the same value (e.g. not if 'Bob' is changed to 'Bob')
- you do not want deleted rows from `dbo.A.Category` to be likewise deleted from `dbo.B.Category`

```sql
MERGE   dbo.B.Category AS tgt
USING   dbo.A.Category AS src
    ON  tgt.[Id] = src.[Id]
WHEN    MATCHED
    AND tgt.[Name] <> src.[Name]
    THEN    UPDATE
            SET     [Name] = src.[Name]
                    , [ArchiveDate] = SYSDATETIME()
WHEN    NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
    THEN    INSERT  ( [Id], [Name], [ArchiveDate] )
            VALUES  ( src.[id], src.[name], SYSDATETIME() ) ;
GO
```